# Accessing command-line arguments from within a c++ program

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

Consider a C++ program made of two CPP files, one of which contains a function named "func()" and the other contains main:

```
void func();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ....
    func();
    ...
}
```

Note that main does not send `argc` and `argv` to func.

Is there any other way by which func can access the command-line arguments? Maybe through some system call?

Comment: In Windows you can call `GetCommandLine()` which returns the raw (unprocessed) command line that argc/argv are built from.

Comment: @JonathanPotter interesting. Is there anything similar in Linux?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi In Linux, you can read `/proc/self/cmdline` file but you have to parse it manually. Each argument in `/proc/self/cmdline` is null-terminated.

Comment: `/proc/self/cmdline` holds the command line for the current process separated by a *nul-character* with an additional (double) *nul-character* terminating the command line.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you do not want to pass the args as a parameter?

Comment: @SKCoder I design a system for automatic grading of homework, where the students write the func.cpp file and I write the tests in the main.cpp file. In the automatic grader, I want to pass some command-line arguments to main.cpp, but want to ensure that the students CANNOT access them from func.cpp, since this can be used for cheating. Now I understand that this might not work, since the students may be able to access the command line arguments in a different way.

Comment: Maybe something with forking may work for you, as you control the arguments of the child process.